# ASP.NET acquire JWT token from ADFS by code or CLI

Tags: asp.net, jwt, adfs

We are developing an ASP.NET (**not .Net Core**) API for another team to consume.
I need to get a JWT token from our ADFS to test if the security of the API is working.

I can't use the login page of ADFS, I need to do this by code, CLI or anything.

How can I do that?

Edit :
I tried to call adfs using postman (POST /adfs/oauth2/token) and got this error :

```
Activity ID: 4acc6a7b-dafe-4a4b-1c00-0080000000dd
Error time: Tue, 03 Aug 2021 08:59:10 GMT
Cookie: enabled
User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios#client-credentials-grant-flow).

It relies on a secret key rather than a login.

You could do this via Postman.

Comment: Which type of application group should I create for this in ADFS please ?

Comment: https://authory.com/RoryBraybrook/Implementing-a-client-credential-flow-in-ADFS-40

Comment: Article is private ^^"

Comment: Sorry - please try again!

Comment: All good thanks, I created the application group and tried to call it with postman.
The call is successful but I get a form with an error without any details (question updated).